# numpy append in a for loop with different sizes

Tags: numpy, for-loop

I have a for loop but  where i has changes by 2  and i want to save a value in a numpy array in each iteration that that changes by 1.

```
n = 8 #steps

# random sequence
rand_seq = np.zeros(n-1)

for i in range(0, (n-1)*2, 2):
    
    curr_state= i+3
```

I want to get curr_state outside the loop in the rand_seq array (seven values).

can you help me with that?

thanks a lot

Comment: For iteration like this, I'd suggest starting with lists, or even a list comprehension.  It should be easier to a beginner to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler version (if I understand the question correctly) would be:

`np.arange(3, 15+1, 2)`

where 3 = start, 15 = stop, 2 = step size.

In general, when using numpy try to avoid adding elements in a for loop as this is inefficient. I would suggest checking out the documentation of `np.arange()`, `np.array()` and `np.zeros()` as in my experience, these will solve 90% of array - creation issues.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand, I changed the np.zeros with the np.arange(0,8,2) but I get an error as I wrote a last command 

rand_seq[i]=curr_state

In order to put each value form the for loop in the rand_seq. Apparently it's more complex what happens in the loop but in the end I have a value (curr_state) that I want to store it externally after each iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can You provide what the output is supposed to look like?

Comment: yeah sure I want : rand_seq=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15] , where each value is form the curr_state  variable in each iteration. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: I edited the answer so now it produces the output You mentioned.

Comment: thanks but where I put it? in the code? sorry I am beginner!

Comment: Well yeah, I'm not sure what You are trying to do but if Your objective was to create an array then its done by this step :)

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward list iteration:

```
In [313]: alist = []
     ...: for i in range(0,(8-1)*2,2):
     ...:     alist.append(i+3)
     ...: 
In [314]: alist
Out[314]: [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

or cast as a list comprehension:

```
In [315]: [i+3 for i in range(0,(8-1)*2,2)]
Out[315]: [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
```

Or if you make an array with the same range parameters:

```
In [316]: arr = np.arange(0,(8-1)*2,2)
In [317]: arr
Out[317]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12])
```

you can add the `3` with one simple expression:

```
In [318]: arr + 3
Out[318]: array([ 3,  5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15])
```

With lists, iteration and comprehensions are great.  With `numpy` you should try to make an array, such as with `arange`, and modify that with whole-array methods (not with iterations).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem is that the loop does something more complicated. I just tried to give a simple example.
I will try to fully edit the question, or delete this one and post a new one. sorry for the confusion